# Powershell is creating directories in its current working directory

Tags: powershell

I am facing a strange situation. I am trying to create a directory structure in C: drive, but new directory structure gets created from where i am running my powershell script, I don't know why is this happening.

```
$new_folder='C:\new_folder' 
new-item $new_folder -type directory
```

If I run the script from desktop , new folder gets created on desktop.
Can someone please help

Comment: `md $new_folder` ? Restart your PS window?

Comment: hi Raf, if i run my code on powershell windows it works fine but if i put this code into a script and run that script it creates folder where i am running the script, just restarted pc as well but no luck

Comment: i closed the window again and ran as admin and it worked,

Comment: In that case write that as an answer, accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate the problem to see if this works better but it may be worth a try:

```
    $new_foldername = 'new_folder'
    $new_folderpath = 'C:\' 
    New-Item -Name $new_foldername -Path $new_folderpath
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to set [ExecutionPolicy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx) for your scripts, because when you are trying to access such resources (as C:\ in your case), you'll not have to worry about it.

Also I had some issues with [relative path](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/def1c794-036d-4918-92ad-f76e6428f750/how-to-use-relative-path-references-in-a-powershell-script-run-by-startjob?forum=ITCG) access to files/folders in C:\ and I had to use [Resolve-Path](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849858.aspx) in order to get script back-on-track.